# Hide Columns from heatMap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I would like to hide columns in my heat map based on year selected from my yearSlicer(rowChart) but not on any other cross filters.

[image]

HeatMap:

```
                heatMap
                    .width(1500)
                    .height(800)
                    .dimension(dimension)
                    .group(FTEMonthGroup)
                    .margins({ left: 200, top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 35 })
                    .keyAccessor(function (d) { return d.key[0]; })
                    .valueAccessor(function (d) { return d.key[1]; })
                    .colorAccessor(function (d) { return +d.value.color; })
                    .title(function (d) {
                        return "Manager:   " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
                            "FTE:  " + d.value.toolTip + "\n" +
                            "Date: " + d.key[0] + "";
                    })
                    .on('renderlet', function (chart) {
                        chart.selectAll("g.cols.axis text")
                            .attr("transform", function () {
                                var coord = this.getBBox();
                                var x = coord.x + (coord.width / 2),
                                    y = coord.y + (coord.height / 2);
                                return "rotate(-45 " + x + " " + y + ")"

                            })
                            .style("text-anchor", "right");
                    });
                heatMap.colorCalculator(function (d, i) {
                    return d.value.color === null ?
                        '#ccc' : heatMap.colors()(d.value.color);
                });
```

**Edit:**

Hidden columns "hide" under the farthest left column resulting in cell overlap:

[image]

Current "working" code (Overlapping cells):

Formatting dates and adding them to an 2D array:

```
            var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");
            var formatTimeYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");
            var formatTimeMonth = d3.timeFormat("%Y - %m");
            data.forEach(function (d) {
                d.Year = formatTimeYear(parseTime(d.Month));
                d.Month = formatTimeMonth(parseTime(d.Month));
            });

                var arrayMonths = {};
                ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d }).top(Infinity).forEach(function (d) {
                    if (arrayMonths[d.Year]) {
                        arrayMonths[d.Year].add(d.Month);
                    } else {
                        arrayMonths[d.Year] = new Set();
                    }
                });
```

onClick called function to "hide" un-selected years:

```
                var yearsHidden = [];
                var hideYear = function (year) {
                    var index = yearsHidden.indexOf(year);
                    if (index === -1) {
                        yearsHidden.push(year);
                    } else {
                        yearsHidden.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                    var yearsHiddenArray = null;
                    yearsHidden.forEach(function (yearAdd) {
                        if (yearsHiddenArray === null) {
                            yearsHiddenArray = Array.from(arrayMonths[yearAdd]);
                        } else {
                            yearsHiddenArray = yearsHiddenArray.concat(Array.from(arrayMonths[yearAdd]));
                        }
                    })
                    heatMap.cols(yearsHiddenArray);
                    heatMap.redraw();
                    // console.log(yearsHiddenArray);
                }
```

yearSlicer(rowChart) onClick:

```
            yearSlicer.on("renderlet.somename", function (chart) {
                chart.selectAll('rect').on("click", function (d) {
                    // console.log("Key: " + d.key);
                    hideYear(d.key);
                });
            });
```

**Edit 2:**

Having some trouble implementing the suggested solution, here is my grouping:

```
            var dimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return [d.Month, d["Manager"]]; }),
                FTEMonthGroup = dimension.group().reduce(
                    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
                        ++p.n;
                        p.color += v.FTE;
                        p.toolTip += v.FTE;
                        return p;
                    },

                    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
                        --p.n;
                        if (p.n === 0) {
                            p.color = null;
                            p.toolTip = null;
                        }
                        return p;
                    },

                    function reduceInitial() {
                        return { n: 0, color: 0, toolTip: 0 };
                    });
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it seems there is a [`cols`](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.heatMap.html) method you can use for this?

Comment: awesome! you should post the solution to help others :)

Comment: @aug Im close, i can hide the columns but they hide under the farthest left  column meaning that said column now has overlapping cells. Will update question with new screen shot.

Comment: @aug iv updated the question to include the new screen shot, and the "working" code that causes the overlapping cells. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, although it seems pretty obvious that `.cols()` and `.rows()` should work as a filter, it looks like the chart still displays every entry in the group, whether or not it is listed in the rows and cols. Since the default is to pull lists of rows and columns from the data, I am not sure that `rows` and `cols` have much effect, except to provide a different ordering if you don't specify `rowOrdering` and `colOrdering`.

I think you'll need to settle for a fake group here, say [filter_bins](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-out-bins-by-a-predicate-function-on-the-values):

```
function filter_bins(source_group, f) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return f(d.value);
            });
        }
    };
}

var filtered_years_group = filter_bins(FTEMonthGroup, function(d) {
    return !yearsHiddenArray.includes(d.Year);
}
heatMap.group(filtered_years_group);
```

... Or something like that. You know the drill!

Comment: Thanks for the help! however im having some difficulty implementing your solution, ive edited my question to include my dimension/grouping if you would be able to further assist me. Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: I don't understand. You'll have to tell me what the problem is.

Comment: Iv added your code into mine however when i select a year the heatmap does not change. Iv added a check in my hideYear function to correct the "Cannot read property 'includes' of null" error caused by the yearsHiddenArray being empty. Thanks

Comment: Really tough to say without having a running example to look at. Obviously you would need to make `yearsHiddenArray` a global. Do you get the idea of how this is supposed to work?

Comment: Glad you got it working! If you have questions in the future, you can fork [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/ckf3d2cv/) and it will have the correct dependencies. Looks like it currently runs in Chrome but not Firefox due to mixed http/https.

Comment: Got the jfiddle to work (ie. split it up into the different sections html, JavaScript and css, and now displays) to show you the non working code as you had said it would be easier to help with a running example of my current code, sorry for the confusion, but i still am having trouble getting the fake group to work. Thanks (Updated Link: https://jsfiddle.net/_M_M_/fLvugo3h/1/ Thanks for the fiddle to fork)

Comment: figured it out! needed to add p.Month = v.Month to my FTEMonthGroup

Comment: Awesome! I figured it was something like that. `console.log ()`, breakpoints, and `debugger` are essential skills for diagnosing data shape problems - I don't think it's possible to use dc.js productively without understanding the dev tools. Sorry I didn't have time to help you more on this problem.

Comment: np, thanks again for all your help. Iv just notice however that if you rapidly click on different years that it has unwanted results, if will show un-selected years, this problem is much more noticeable with my larger data set. Iv updated my jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/_M_M_/fLvugo3h/4/ if you have a chance to look at it that would be great! Thanks (reset button for yearSlicer also dosnt appear to work when using my lager data set....)

Comment: Okay, I'll try to take a look later today. If it helps, I do not recall seeing these kinds of issues using raw dc.js - not to say that it's not a bug in the library, it certainly could be. I won't speculate on the cause until I look more closely. If you only run into problems with a large data set, it will be hard for me to test unless you provide a version with lots of data.

Comment: still have the rapid clicking problem but i did fix the reset button. Needed to move a method outside of my d3.csv().then as my jsfiddle is coded a little different due to not loading in a csv file.

Comment: Yeah that's just the usual javascript troubleshooting and not really appropriate content for SO, at least for someone as skilled as you seem to be. If you post a fiddle with a large dataset, preferably as another question, I'll be glad to look at the rapid clicks issue. Mods are about to get angry at us for this long conversation...